# Разбитие строки, начиная например со строки номер 23 (или любой другой)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать, поиск и разбитие с определённой строки.
Есть динамический файл, в котором периодически добавляются строки.
Файл address:

```
OpenVPN CLIENT LIST
Updated,Fri Jan  4 17:10:16 2019
Common Name,Real Address,Bytes Received,Bytes Sent,Connected Since
AABBCCDDEEFF,192.168.10.1:54054,82933647,38303313,Fri Dec 28 15:24:40 2018
A1B2C2D2E2F2,192.168.10.2:37007,75520723,36819438,Fri Dec 28 15:25:12 2018
A3B3C3D3E3F3,192.168.10.3:34977,556668317,387416490,Wed Dec 26 21:47:28 2018
ROUTING TABLE
Virtual Address,Common Name,Real Address,Last Ref
11.11.11.1,AABBCCDDEEFF,192.168.10.1:54054,Fri Jan  4 17:24:03 2019
11.11.11.2,A1B2C2D2E2F2,192.168.10.1:60677,Fri Jan  4 17:24:02 2019
11.11.11.3,A3B3C3D3E3F3,192.168.10.1:34977,Fri Jan  4 17:24:04 2019
GLOBAL STATS
Max bcast/mcast queue length,0
END
```

Из этого файла нужно получать только 11.11.11.1, 11.11.11.2, 11.11.11.3 и т.д.
Минуя верхнюю часть файла.
Если я редактирую в ручную файл, т.е. удаляю всю верхнюю часть, оставляя только вот это в файле:

11.11.11.1,AABBCCDDEEFF,192.168.10.1:54054,Fri Jan 4 17:24:03 2019 11.11.11.2,A1B2C2D2E2F2,192.168.10.1:60677,Fri Jan 4 17:24:02 2019 11.11.11.3,A3B3C3D3E3F3,192.168.10.1:34977,Fri Jan 4 17:24:04 2019

То у меня работает такой код:

```
#!/usr/bin python3
import time
from datetime import datetime
import datetime
import paramiko
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy)
file = open('/usr/local/bin/address', 'r')
for line in file:

    info = {}
    info['ip'] = line.split(',')[0]
    info['mac'] = line.split(',')[1]
```

Как сделать что бы не приходилось редактировать вручную?

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('/usr/local/bin/address') as fh:
    for i, line in enumerate(fh):
        if i < 23:
            continue
        info = {}
        info['ip'], info['mac'] = line.split(',')
```

или

```
with open('/usr/local/bin/address') as fh:
    for _ in range(23):
        next(fh)
    for line in fh:
        info = {}
        info['ip'], info['mac'] = line.split(',')
```

или

```
import itertools

with open('/usr/local/bin/address') as fh:
    for line in itertools.islice(fh, 23, None):
        info = {}
        info['ip'], info['mac'] = line.split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('address.txt') as f:
    nums = f.read().splitlines()

info = []

for line in [ [a for a in (i.split(',')[0], i.split(',')[1])] for i in nums if i[:8]=='11.11.11' ]:
    info.append(dict([('ip', line[0])]))
    info.append(dict([('mac', line[1])]))


print(info)
[{'ip': '11.11.11.1'}, {'mac': 'AABBCCDDEEFF'}, {'ip': '11.11.11.2'}, {'mac': 'A1B2C2D2E2F2'}, {'ip': '11.11.11.3'}, {'mac': 'A3B3C3D3E3F3'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Хорошо, если номер строки заведомо известен. Что же произойдет, если номер строки не совпадет? Скорее лучше использовать в данном случае регулярное выражение для поиска строк, соответствующих шаблону *^(\d+.){3}\d+*, то есть без валидации корректности IP-адресов, являющихся началом искомых строк. В переводе на Python это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
from re import compile

r = compile('^(\d+\.){3}\d+')
with open('/usr/local/bin/address') as f:
   res = [dict(zip(['ip', 'mac'], l.split(',')[:2])) for l in f.readlines() if r.match(l)]
print(res)
# [{'ip': '11.11.11.1', 'mac': 'AABBCCDDEEFF'}, {'ip': '11.11.11.2', 'mac': 'A1B2C2D2E2F2'}, {'ip': '11.11.11.3', 'mac': 'A3B3C3D3E3F3'}]
```

Другой вопрос: существуют ли в файле и прочие строки, подпадающие под данный шаблон, которых в конечном выводе быть не должно? Если так, то шаблон придется подправить, дополнив его таким образом, чтобы отсеивалось лишнее.

Comment: В том то и дело, что файл динамический, строка 23 просто для примера, она может быть и 10 и 133 строкой. Попробую ваш вариант, спасиб